# Linking errors when compiling code with OpenCV Libraries

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation

I'm trying to compile a sample program after installing Opencv with the command:

```
g++ hello-world.cpp -o hello-world -I /usr/local/include/opencv -L /usr/local/lib -lm -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux
```

however, I'm getting an error that says:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcv  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhighgui  
/uer/bin/ld: cannot find -lcvaux
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What do I need to do to correct this?? I installed opencv by downloading the latest stable version and using cmake to create the build files, then ran make install from the command line.

Was there anything I may have missed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add another `-L` argument specifying the actual location of the OpenCV libraries.

Comment: so instead of -L /usr/local/lib have -L <library location>? or an additional -L... and where would I find the libraries? When I do a make install, it shows me all the files are up to date and the location... but theres so many different things... all the .h files are in /usr/local/include/opencv... do the library files have a different extension?

Comment: Go through the cmake output to find out.

Comment: thanks for your quick response - editied my above comment but by the time I did, you had already responded. I think I may be unclear on what I'm really looking for. When I do a make install, it shows me all the files are up to date and the location... but theres so many different things... all the .h files are in /usr/local/include/opencv... do the library files have a different extension?

Comment: ok, all of those seem to be in /usr/local/lib/ - let me try this out - thanks

Comment: mmm... the thing is I already have the -L argument with their location in g++ hello-world.cpp -o hello-world -I /usr/local/include/opencv -L /usr/local/lib -lm -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux since the ".so" files are located in /usr/local/lib... or am I still missing something here? I tried adding another -L with that same location after -lcvaux and it gave me the same error...

Comment: hmmm... well none actually... I do have a bunch that would match libopencv_*.so, and for each * in the previous statement, there are 3 files; ending in .so, .so.2.2, and .so.2.2.0

Comment: so for example, I have "libopencv_highgui.so", "libopencv_highgui.so.2.2", and "libopencv_highgui.so.2.2.0"

Comment: Then your `-l` arguments are wrong. Try `-lopencv_highgui` and the like.

Comment: I couldn't find the replacements for -lcv or -lcvaux, so I just took them out, but I changed -lhighgui to -lopencv_highgui and it worked! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 34):

UPDATED-

Better use this command:

```
g++ opencv.cpp -o opencv -L `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

The `pkg-config` command will locate the correct include and library for your source code.
For better handling with OpenCV programming go with an IDE like `code::block`.

Maybe this tutorial will help you in OpenCV programming with `code::block`:
[How to Setup OpenCV for code :: block in Linux and Windows?](http://hxr99.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-setup-opencv-for-code-block-in.html)

Comment: For OpenCV 4 you should use 
```g++ opencv.cpp -o opencv -L `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

Answer (score 21):

Recently I started using OpenCV and I got similar problem and for me this works really well:

```
-lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: with the addition of -lopencv_videoio this worked for me but i don't understand why we need to do this? I mean i already included the libraries and pkg-config lists all libraries. I started learning c++ recently but this is so different than other languages.