# Can't compile opencv in linux

Tags: linux, opencv, compilation, g++

I've been having trouble trying to compile using g++ in linux some sample of the sample code for opencv but I get this error message after I run:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` hello.cpp -o hello
```

I get this output:

```
/tmp/ccjvVxLI.o: In function `main':
hello.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
hello.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `cvNamedWindow'
hello.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `cvShowImage'
hello.cpp:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `cvWaitKey'
hello.cpp:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to `cvDestroyWindow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've looked online and checked my installation of OpenCV and I get the normal output for:

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv
```

as:

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include
```

But when I ran:

```
pkg-config --libs opencv
```

I got a weird list that looks like this:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so     /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
```

If it helps I installed Opencv2.4.1 on ubuntu LTS 12.04 with the help of this site: http://www.samontab.com/web/2012/06/installing-opencv-2-4-1-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o hello hello.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Comment: You can call pkg-config like `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`, too.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the
>   linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order
>   they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after
>   file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’,
>   those functions may not be loaded.

So the `pkg-config --libs opencv` has to come at the end of the the filename, else gcc will not be able to resolve the symbols.

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, a few words of explanation would go a long way to making this answer valuable to future readers.

Comment: Thanks @TheThom for pointing that out. I'll mill make sure I add required explanations in future answers.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this thread:

[compiling code with OpenCV Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559945/compiling-code-with-opencv-libraries/17443128#17443128)

Adding these as command line arguments also works very well:

-lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect