# Sample Program From Terminal Could Not Run

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I'm new to opencv in ubuntu.  I've follow the tutorial from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) for setting up the opencv in linux. However, I have failed to make the [sample program](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) runs. After I type the following,

```
$ g++ DisplayImage.cpp
```

These error appears,

```
/tmp/cc3GTOtQ.o: In function `main':
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x113): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x147): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x169): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/tmp/cc3GTOtQ.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/cc3GTOtQ.o: In function `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)':
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_[cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)]+0x111): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
/tmp/cc3GTOtQ.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[cv::Mat::release()]+0x47): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full command line build C++ program with OpenCV Libraries.

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -L/usr/local/lib/ -g -o binaryName  main.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy
```

If you installed OpenCV in different location, you should change the path of 'include' and lib 'directory' to appropriate location.

**Edit:-**

Instead of running this command every time just create a file `build.sh` in your project directory, change it's permission to executable by running `chmod 777 build.sh` and for building the project just run this file.

Comment: Hi. This works perfectly fine. Do I have to type all this every time I create a new project?

Comment: You can create a file with this content and change it's permission to executable, whenever you need to build your project run it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with the opencv libraries: probably you'll need to add at least `-lcv` and maybe `-lcxcore` and `-lhighgui` to your command line. See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559945/compiling-code-with-opencv-libraries).

Comment: It's still doesn't work. For your information I create a folder at the desktop and the .cpp is located there. I use it VS2008 previously where I need to link the libraries, environment variable stuff and include the dependencies. I would like to try to compile from the terminal but I couldn't.