# OpenCV SFM Module Reconstruct Method Linking Error

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use opencv sfm module.I installed sfm module with all dependencies.
I can use all opencv methods without reconstruct method.I have a problem with this method.I have linker error i searched on internet.But i couldn't solve the problem.

Link : [compiling code with OpenCV Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559945/compiling-code-with-opencv-libraries)

I found this and a lot of topic but i dont know how can i solve this problem

This is my cmake file:

```
    project(x)
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

    find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

    include_directories(/usr/include/eigen3)
    include_directories(/usr/local/include/opencv2/sfm)
    set(OpenCV_LIBS -L. -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video -lopencv_viz -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_sfm -lpthread)

    add_executable(x main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(x ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

And this is error :

```
    undefined reference to `cv::sfm::reconstruct(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, bool)'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: if you already have `find_package`, why do you re-define `OpenCV_LIBS`?

Comment: Are you able to use other Opencv APIs ? Like `cv::Mat()` etc ?

Comment: @ZdaR i can. If i remove reconstruct method, everything works.

Comment: @QuangHoang it doesn't change anything. i removed it didn't change anything error is same.